# Remove all activities of an app from every existing task in Activity Back Stack

Tags: android, android-activity, task

Is there a way of removing all activities belonging to the app in foreground (my app)?

The activities might be present in different tasks. Also after removing all activities my app should return to home screen which is launcher activity of my app.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to finish all activities and go to main activity

Comment: yes, Jyoti. But clearing task flag doesn't work.

Comment: use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Comment: Do you have any usecase, which requires you to revisit those activities? Or all activities are used only once?

Comment: I have 3 activities A, B, C. A is launcher and is in  standard launch mode. A starts B throgh intent. B in turn starts C through intent. C again starts B through intent. (B-C) or (C-B) can alternate any number of times. Note that B and C has been kept in singleTask launchmode. Now when in B I want to go to A by finish both existing activities, i.e, A and B. I don't know whether they are in same task. The when I arrive in A my app should behave as it was just launched. i.e, remove all data and everything.

Comment: Problem is I am able to arrive at A as expected but again when I want to go to A it goes to B and suddenly crashes and return to A. When I try again, It works fine.

Comment: Generally there is no reason to have multiple tasks and your use of special launch modes `singleTask` or `singleInstance` will cause these problems. Please explain why you think you need multiple tasks!

Answer (score 1):

**You need to call your activity like this.**

```
Intent login=new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
login.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
login.putExtra("flag",false);
startActivity(login);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Any existing task that would be associated with the current activity to be cleared before the desired activity is started. Simply **`old activities are finished.`**

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

If set, this activity will **`become the start of a new task`** on this history stack.

for more details, **[`Intent Flags`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)**

Comment: But old activities in another task are not destroyed and that's causing problem

Comment: why don't you try single task? `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for all activities

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    // set the new task and clear flags
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
finish();
```